# Why retrieving system info return null point of exception?

Tags: java, swing, runtime, nullpointerexception, swingworker

I have traying to get system info with `Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);`

I get following error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:422)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:326)
    at mytest.SystemInfoToTextArea.doInBackground(SystemInfoToTextArea.java:31)
    at mytest.SystemInfoToTextArea.doInBackground(SystemInfoToTextArea.java:16)
```

**Any suggestion welcome**

**Code of class**

```
public class SystemInfoToTextArea extends SwingWorker<String, Void> {
private JTextArea textArea;
private String cmd;

public SystemInfoToTextArea(JTextArea textArea, String cmd) {
    textArea = textArea;
    cmd = cmd;
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground() throws Exception {
    String outputMem = null;
    try {
        String lineMem;
        outputMem = "";
        Process procMem = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
        BufferedReader input =
                new BufferedReader
                        (new InputStreamReader(procMem.getInputStream()));
        while ((lineMem = input.readLine()) != null) {
            outputMem = (lineMem + "\n");

        }

        input.close();
    } catch (Exception err) {
        err.printStackTrace();
    }
    return outputMem;
}

@Override
protected void done() {
    super.done();
    try {
        textArea.append(get());
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

public static void main(String... args){
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setSize(700,500);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea("System info");

    panel.add(textArea);
    frame.setContentPane(panel);

    frame.setVisible(true);

    SystemInfoToTextArea systemInfoToTextArea = new SystemInfoToTextArea(textArea,"cmd /C dir");
     systemInfoToTextArea.execute();

}
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Your `cmd` is obviously `null` because your constructor code is wrong. Write

```
this.cmd = cmd;
```

Same for textArea.

Answer (score 3):

You constructor doesn't do what you think:

```
public SystemInfoToTextArea(JTextArea textArea, String cmd) {
    textArea = textArea;
    cmd = cmd;
}
```

This just reassigns the parameters (to their own values!), and doesn't set the *fields* with the same names. What you want to do is prefix them with this:

```
public SystemInfoToTextArea(JTextArea textArea, String cmd) {
    this.textArea = textArea;
    this.cmd = cmd;
}
```

A decent IDE would warn you of this mistake.

Comment: Doesn't even reassign, it's a no-op :)

Comment: I use Intellij, he didn't warn or complain.

Comment: after correcting the constructor i ger this error: ´java.io.IOException: CreateProcess: free -m -t -o error=2
 at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
 at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(ProcessImpl.java:81)
 at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:30)
 at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:451)
 at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:591)
 at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:429)
 at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:326)
 at mytest.SystemInfoToTextArea.doInBackground(SystemInfoToTextArea.java:31)

  ´

Comment: Thanks everyone. I changed String command in the main to "cmd /C dir" and it works. I have corrected it in the code.